# Is there a way to mount another partition on startup?

Tags: mount, dual-boot

I have a secondary partition with a broken Windows installation on my hard drive. I no longer need Windows, but I still have some files that I need there.

The partition remained mounted when my Windows system crashed, so I can only mount it as read only using this command:

```
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda2 /media/Windows
```

Is there a way to execute this command during the boot process? I can't seem to execute this command without a `sudo` privilege.

Comment: It's totally unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please give us more details why you need it mounted during the boot, not afterwards. If you simply need it mounted - place it into /etc/fstab

Comment: I'm just trying to avoid typing that command over and over again every time I start the system. Sorry, I thought that this would be easy to assume from the current content.

Comment: it was too easy, so I assumed there was some hidden pithole :) @embik already answered your question with my suggestion to use "/etc/fstab" file for auto-mount

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to run this as a command during boot, you can achieve read-only mounting via the file `/etc/fstab`. `/etc/fstab` contains all filesystems that should be mounted upon boot and that's exactly what you want. It's also possible to add the `mount` options (for example, `ro` for read-only) to an `/etc/fstab` entry.

The additional line you need to add to the file (for example, via `sudo nano /etc/fstab`) looks like this:

```
/dev/sda2 /media/Windows ntfs ro 0 2
```

If you're interested in a cleaner way of creating that line, you'll need the UUID of your partition - The /dev/sdx allocation may change if you're adding different disks or even USB media (most likely it does not, nonetheless you're safer with using the UUID). To display the partition's UUID, run `sudo blkid /dev/sda2` and change the line you have to match this syntax:

```
UUID=<UUID for /dev/sda2> /media/Windows ntfs ro 0 2
```

After saving the file, run `sudo mount -a` to make sure your partition is mounted properly (unmount the partition before to make sure it really works).

Answer (score 1):

I have multiple partitions that I wanted mounted automatically: I have set that with the 'Disks' tool (`gnome-disk-utility`) present in the default repos.

- Select the drive you want and access its mount options after clicking the small gears button
- Un-check the 'automatic mount', enable 'mount at startup' and set the mount point:

[image]

The mount point changes also when one of the options under 'Identify as' menu is changed. I have found most convenient the 'Identify as' option that has the form 'LABEL=Label-of-your-drive'.

Labels can be easily edited

- with Gparted - details on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/153183/47206) - also [on youtube] (https://youtu.be/Cf9Wb_13ew8)
- with Disks - details [on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/276928/47206)

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different need, I wanted to mount partition at the graphical session start and following the gvfs schema.
To be clearer I wanted the partition to be mounted like its icon had been clicked in Files.

In order to do that I created a simple shell script `mount-data-partition.sh` with content:

```
#!/bin/sh
gio mount --device=/dev/<my partition device>
```

put it into a path that is in my login shell (in my case the default bash) PATH, opened **System Settings > Applications > Startup** and finally added a custom command using just the name of the script `mount-data-partition.sh`.

This does correctly mount the device at the gvfs default **/media/{username}/{label}**  path and the mount can be unmounted from Files.

You could use fstab and add a rule for the same mount point but it would be fixed and not depending on the label (or the user). Also Files would not be able to umount it without authentication.