# How change the default installation path?

Tags: software-installation, disk-management, filesystem

Or how to install programs on multiple disks?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to mount another partition on startup?](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/605/is-there-a-way-to-mount-another-partition-on-startup)

Comment: Actually, you ask two questions here and both of them have already been answered at this site. However, if you can describe your scenario more precisely we might help you more

Comment: @lemonslice kindly provide the link to the second answer as well, which would be useful for others who may come across this question.

Comment: The default installation path for installing the system, or for installing individual programs with `apt`? Needs clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really change installation path as unixes use a fixed file system hierarchy. To understand the file system layout in elementary OS you can see https://askubuntu.com/questions/138547/how-to-understand-the-ubuntu-file-system-layout (Ubuntu and elementary OS share the same layout).

As of installing on multiple disks, you can mount them as part of your file system.